# Why like button does not publish feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am using like button on my application.It works fine but it does not shows any feed?
any idea for this ?

Comment: I think your button needs some grease, it looks like it is stuck. Seriously, not much for us to work on here...

Comment: Is this an XFBML, iframe or API like button?  What kind of feed are you expecting to get?

Comment: i am using iframe.I just want newsfeed that shows that user like....url

Answer (score 1):

If the URL you are liking is not publicly accessible then this would explain why. Facebook will visit shared/liked URLs for verification.